# Hi, Using java regex how can i get the class body between two curly braces

Tags: java

```
public class NewtonsLaw
    {
        public static Integer force(Integer m,Integer n,Integer h)
        {
            Integer p = m*2+n+h;
            return p;
        }
        public static int force3(Integer m)
        {
            Integer q= 23;
            return m;
        }
}
```

So i want the content of the whole class body (between the curly braces).. pls help.

Comment: As the output i want : 
public static Integer force(Integer m,Integer n,Integer h) { Integer p = m*2+n+h; return p; } public static int force3(Integer m) { Integer q= 23; return m; }

Comment: i dont get your question

Comment: Using java regular expression how can i take out the whole content of a class like as i had written above class NewtonsLaw, I want the output using java regular expression as:                                                                      public static Integer force(Integer m,Integer n,Integer h)
        {
            Integer p = m*2+n+h;
            return p;
        }
        public static int force3(Integer m)
        {
            Integer q= 23;
            return m;
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use indexes;

```
String s = "public class NewtonsLaw{public static Integer force(Integer m,Integer n,Integer h) {    Integer p = m*2+n+h;  return p;   } public static int force3(Integer m) {    Integer q= 23;            return m;        }       }";

System.out.println(s.substring(s.indexOf("{") + 1,s.lastIndexOf("}") - 1));
```

EDIT: with regex;

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{(.*?)\\}$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: thanks buddy. actually i was looking for java regex. If we can use the regex it wl be very helpful to us. Thanks again

Comment: Its working if the entire string is a single line. but it did not work if i it is a multiline string like:  String s =" @isTest\n"
+"private class TestNewtonsLaw {\n"
   +"/**\n"
   +" * Test method for NewtonsLaw#force()2.\n"
   +" */\n"
   +" private static testmethod void testForce2() {\n"
          +"Test.startTest();\n"
          +" NewtonsLaw obj = new NewtonsLaw();\n"
         +" obj.force2(null);\n"
         +" System.assert(null, null);\n"
         +" Test.stopTest();\n"
         +"  }\n"
       +"}";